# "Maybe" case for nth-Term Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble fully understanding the *n*th-term test for determining convergence in a series. It is stated within the procedure that:

> If $$\lim_{n\rightarrow∞} a_{n}=0$$ holds true (or *maybe*) for the series
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{∞}c_{n}(x-a)^{n}$$
>   Proceed to the next test.

I don't understand how "$\lim_{n\rightarrow∞} a_{n}$" can *potentially* (*maybe*) result in a value of zero – I considered oscillating series' limits, however those series would be classified as divergent.

Comment: This is my first post on this network; please provide me with comments if anything can be improved. Thanks!

Comment: Does $c_n$ equal $a_n$?

Comment: $n$th term test isn't going to help with power series.  You need the ratio test.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes. I have updated the question.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I believe not.

Comment: Question is fairly unclear.  What is the connection between $a_n$ and your stated power series?  Do you wish to consider $a_n = c_n(x-a)^n$ for fixed $a$?

Comment: @Randall I am considering the series for constant $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at it.  Consider the power series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (x-1)^n.
$$
With $x=2$ you get
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} 
$$
which converges, and $c_n \to 0$.  With $x=0$ you get
$$
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}
$$
which now diverges even though $c_n \to 0$.  In both cases, the terms $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (x-1)^n$ go to $0$ termwise.  Therefore, be very careful.

Is this an answer?

Comment: After more in-depth exploration with series, I was able to understand what you were saying. Thanks!

Comment: Haha you're welcome!   Glad it helped.